# After macOS Mojave update - iterm and zsh broken

Tags: iterm2, zshrc, macos-mojave

After updating to Mojave the iterm / zsh and theme are broken

I have configured it as tunnckoCore configuration:https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Show-Off-Your-Config

and i have updated via brew. I'm lost to what has been broken or how to to search for a solution. I have restarted zshrc, iterm2, and etc.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to reinstall oh-my-zsh, first uninstall it deleting the directory (if you don't know try install direct and the terminal will give you the path)

`rm -rf /Users/YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME/.oh-my-zsh`

so after install zsh

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Comment: Note that you may need to restore any changes made to your _.zshrc_ file. A backup on updating seems to be saved to: _.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh_

Comment: You can also uninstall by running `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` from the command line, instead of the rm -rf above.

Comment: Felipe Castro, actually this `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` command doesn't work for old zsh version. So, if someone come because above issue it means they dont have the updated stuff...

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause is the default font, I have the same issue after the update.
Try the following:

```
open iTerm -> Cmd + i -> Text -> Change Font -> Source Code Pro for Powerline
```

Anything which ends with `for Powerline` really.